# Apache Druid batch ingestion - low performance of index task

Tags: performance, batch-processing, druid

I read the following tutorial:
http://druid.io/docs/latest/tutorials/tutorial-loading-batch-data.html
and put the data into druid using index_task. 
I also issued time boundary query and everything worked fine.

However when i tried to insert large amount of data (~ 2 000 000 records) it takes too much time.

Is it possible to improve performance of index_task and how to do it?

Is it possible by:

- change of segment granuality?
- replace index_task with HadoopDruidIndexer?
- split data to smaller parts and inserts it concurrently?
- increase number of nodes or memory per node?
- anything else?

Please help.

Comment: how much is "too much" in your case?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We had the same problem, the index task is not very optimize to ingest large amount of data. They write it in the documentation: *"They are however, slow when the data volume exceeds 1G."* It's better to use either real time ingestion (Tranquility) or [Index Hadoop Task](http://druid.io/docs/latest/misc/tasks.html#index-hadoop-task). The Index Hadoop Task is the best solution if you need to batch-ingest large amount of data. It scales well and it's significantly faster.

Comment: but, what if we have data(.json files) in HDFS?

Answer (score 1):

Recent work on druid did serious improvement to the indexing task. Also both Index Hadoop task and index task do the same thing.

Comment: can you elaborate on this? The docs indicate the index task is not intended for production workloads, is it it really _identical_? I thought it does not scale well since there is no scheduler? Thanks

Comment: Even we are facing issues with index_parallel tasks. It takes around 6-8hrs to ingest around 20GB of data.Can you elaborate how they’ve  are doing the same thing?